# TCP data lost after reconnect.

Tags: c#, python, tcp

I'm working on a test suite where a Python program starts and tests a C# program and terminates it after the test finished. The C# program is started multiple times, one after another (so start, test, kill, start, test, kill etc.)

The C# program has a TCP server, Python connects to it and issues some actions to test.

However, from time to time, data gets lost. I've captured the TCP data and debugged through the code, but cannot find the exact reason. The dump looks quite strange to me, maybe you can help?

[image: Wireshark Screenshot]

Frames up to 773 show one test (Python on port 49xxx, C# on 2000). Data is exchanged, then Python closes the connection on 771. This part works.

I have no idea why RST is sent at 773, but I'm not a tcp expert.

Starting with 774 the C# app has been restarted and Python tries to connect to it. This looks weird. Data is sent in 779 and 781, but does not appear in C#.

Here my app hangs, Python waits for the response, C# waits for incomming data.

Comment: This probably isn't the issue since you are running everything over localhost but I will throw it out there.  Are you logged in as an administrator?  If not, are you running these programs as an administrator?  I have seen cases where Windows will kill network connections from untrusted software if you are not running as an admin.

Comment: If you notice in the trace there are a bunch of ACKs that are occurring together.  This indicates that the receiving side of connection is not keeping up with the send rate.  You will also notice the sequence numbers are repeating which indicates the packets are being resent.  I would try to increase the time before a packet is resent.  The receiver end of the connection is running slow and not ack packets which cause the packets to get resent.  Eventually the send side of connection closes because it doesn't get an ack for a packet.

Comment: Maybe I don't get you right, but I can't see a single retransmit in the log. Both ends of the connection do send and receive, the data rate is pretty low.
Starting with 774 the clients source port changed, so it's a different connection.

Answer (score 0):

Guess I've found the problem. The output of wireshark above guided me in the wrong direction, the more I think about the more it looks perfectly fine even if wireshark marks the transmissions red/black.

```
IAsyncResult asyncResult=null;
while(!_abort.WaitOne(0))
{
    if(asyncResult==null)
    asyncResult=_tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(null, null);

    var waitResult=asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000);
    if(!waitResult) continue;

    var tcpClient=_tcpListener.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyncResult);
    asyncResult=null;

    _newClientHandler(tcpClient);
}
```

This is the code on the C# side that handles incomming connections. After digging into the docs, it seems that asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle has no internal state. WaitOne only returns true if it's signalled within the time WaitOne runs.

Because I've used lots of ManualResetEvents around, I missed that point. So if a connection request is accepted between BeginAcceptTcpClient and the following WaitOne the code gets stuck.